# How to save a list of objects in spring web mvc

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Can I save a list of objects in a transaction like we normally save single objects using `session#save(object)` I tried this code to save a list of objects,

```
public List<TfmImage> save(List<TfmImage> images) {
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction transaction = createTransaction(session);
        try {
            session.save(images);
            commitTransaction(transaction);
            session.refresh(images);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            closeSession(session);
        }
        return images;
    }
```

but it is throwing exception , `MappingException` and the detailed message is,
`unknownEntity : java.util.ArrayList` **from the detail message, it is clear that ArrayList is not an entity in my project** How can I save the list of objects? Do I have to iterate through the list and save then one by one? Is there an efficient way to save a list of objects like we normally save single object.

Comment: Either you have to run a for loop or try checking hibernate batch save or update processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do it as follows because list is not mapped to a entity.TfmImage is mapped to entity. so, should be saved separately

```
    @Tranasactioal
    public void write(List<T> modelObjectList) throws Exception{
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            for(T t : modelObjectList){
                session.save(t);
            }
        }
```